# Tar'ing using wildcards where one type may not exist

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I have a shell script to automate the creation of separate tar files for several directories; cd'ing to each and calling the command:

```
tar cf pakage1.tar *.csv *.fmt
```

Most directories contain .fmt and .csv files, I need a solution for when a *.csv may not exist but *.fmt does and therefore a tar is required.  I haven't found an 'ignore wildcard if not found' command, does one exist?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Ack!  Tarballs should always be built to extract into a subdirectory.  Do not specify multiple files as arguments.  Instead, always specify a single directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` in combination with `xargs`:

```
find . \( -name '*.csv' -or -name '*.fmt' \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar cf pakage1.tar
```

`-print0` and `-0` to use null-separators instead of spaces otherwise it will choke on filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: -o instead of -or on Solaris 10